# Facebook Real Time Update return only "changed_fields":["feed"] and not the actual comment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to implement Facebook Real Time Update in a proper manner. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/).

Everything is done according to the instructions given in this page, but the returned JSON from Facebook is missing interesting information.

The JSON is for example:

```
{"object":"user","entry":[{"uid":"1408932149","id":"1408932149","time":1370253930,"changed_fields":["feed"]}]}
```

But the event that induced the event was a comment on a facebook-page. I want more information. For example the id of the post, id of the comment and similar vital information.

Why is Facebook only returning that the field "feed" changed and not the id of the comment?

Regards,
Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was fairly easy once I realised it.

It the Facebook developer page for pages (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#realtime). This question is the result if one only does step 1 and fails in doing step 2 and 3.

Having done that, and carefully using the access_token for the page, everything started working and now it works fine. Not really within the five seconds promised by Facebook, but good enough.

I have also found that using an a api such as Facebook SDK for .NET (http://facebooksdk.net/) can be very rewarding, but it might make it harder to understand the api presented by Facebook.

Comment: Unsure why this was accepted.  Clearly the question was about a user and not a page.

Comment: If one doesn't do step 2 and 3, then Facebook (real time update) don't know which app is connected to a page, and thus only returning a feed.   Therefore the response could trick you and make you think that it's relating to user and not a page. Facebook API is a bit complicated and I had to spend some time learning it to understand how pieces fit together.

Answer (score 1):

Update: found this, sounds promising:
http://allfacebook.com/page-posts-real-time-updates-api_b111225

I have the same problem. As far as I can tell, this is what FB's system was designed to do, even though we would really LIKE to get higher granularity information pushed (and it would likely be more efficient for FB's servers, since as it is now, developers may have to write code that digs through the feed to find the relevant comment or such, possibly fetching quite a lot of stuff we through away, just to get one comment).

Bummer. If anyone has any good ideas to offer, I'd be grateful. We want our app to react to certain comments on a user's wall, which we do already for the user's own status updates, but to do it for comments it looks like we would have to scrape the whole feed (which sounds impractical at scale), since the new comment could be on an old status update.

Comment: We have implemented the real time update according to the api, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#realtime, and it's working just fine. However, our implementation relates to a page and not a user.

Comment: Update: as of Jan 16 2014 this is still not implemented in the realtime API

Answer (score -1):

You receives RTU from "Web hooks" - it is more simple feature.

If you want receive RTU with next format:
`{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"593349087454592","time":1445698004,"changes":[{"field":"feed","value":{"item":"post","verb":"add","post_id":"593349087454592_787861828003316","is_hidden":false,"sender_id":1442769135993502,"message":"Post #4","sender_name":"Sheva Che"}}]}]}`

you should setup RTU with help of Graph API. Below you can see several examples of operations:

[image: View RTU subscriptions]

[image: Subscribe For RTU]

Hope it will be useful